# how to pass jaxb object to camelconfig xml file

Tags: jaxb

I am trying to use jaxb in camel routing.I have tried to load router from xml using jaxb and got it done. Inside a method I have created jaxb object and unmarshaller the router in xml(loaded router from xml).

### my code:

```
    JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(Constants.JAXB_CONTEXT_PACKAGES);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxb.createUnmarshaller();
    Resource rs = new ClassPathResource("cameltest.xml");
    Object value = unmarshaller.unmarshal(rs.getInputStream());
    RoutesDefinition routes = (RoutesDefinition) value;

    context.addRouteDefinitions(routes.getRoutes());
```

Requirement:

Instead of doing it in java file. I need when a method in a service is called, the jaxb object inside the method should trigger off the xml which contains the flow (router concept). help me........

Answer (score 1):

Using JAXB **in** a Camel route is quite easy, as is shown in [JAXB](http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html). Unless the processing is very complex it can be done in Spring and requires a minimal amount of code.

What it looks like you are trying to do from the code is extract the routes using JAXB from the Camel xml file, perhaps you are wanting to create dynamic router - I would suggest looking at the [EIP Patterns](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) that Camel implements and picking something like the Content Based Router or Dynamic Router.